# How to deal with lists in AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a HTML file that takes in input:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="TP" id="TP" value="[8,9]"  style="text-align:center" placeholder="Enter true positive value."/> 
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="FP" id="FP" value="7"  style="text-align:center" placeholder="Enter false positive value."/>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="FN" id="FN" value="6" style="text-align:center" placeholder="Enter false negative value."/>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="TN" id="TN" value="5" style="text-align:center" placeholder="Enter true negative value."/>
```

I have an AJAX script that takes this input values from the HTML doc and sends the inputs to a Python function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('form').on('submit', function(event) {
       $.ajax({
          data : {
             truePositive : $('#TP').val(),
             falsePositive : $('#FP').val(),
             falseNegative : $('#FN').val(),
             falsePositive : $('#FP').val(),
                 },
             type : 'POST',
             url : '/out'
            })
        .done(function(data) {
          $('#output').text(data.output).show();
      });
      event.preventDefault();
      });
});
```

My question is how does AJAX knows that one of my input is a list rather than an integer?
e.g.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="TP" id="TP" value="[8,9]"  style="text-align:center" placeholder="Enter true positive value."/>
```

Comment: Dont think ajax will ever know it, It will be considered as string only

Comment: Well, ofcourse you can apply string operations on the received value. That would make it "list-interpretable"

Comment: *If* you wish to convert string `[8,9]` to actual array and later use in JS, then do `JSON.parse($('#TP').val())`

Comment: I'm curious about the tagging.  Why was it more preferable to include a `css` tag over `python`? Also, you say list, but your example is an array.  In certain languages, lists and arrays are similar but different constructs.  Are you trying to distinguish numbers from non-numbers and what action are you trying to accomplish?  Finally, why don't change the value of your input `name`s to be the key you want to send over AJAX and use jQuery's `.serialize()` to do the heavy work for you?

Answer (score 0):

When receiving the string in python you could parse it to an array:

```
arr_received = "[8, 9]"
arr_to_be_parsed = arr_received[1:-1]
# "8, 9"
arr_parsed = arr_to_be_parsed.split(',')
# ['8', '9']
```

Or a one liner:

```
arr = arr_received[1:-1].split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax doesn't know it's a list, not even an integer, he just passes it as a string. It is in the code behind where you must receive that value and parse it as a list (or a class) to be able to work it that way.